# Error when injecting websocket service in Angular 2 application

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular2-services

I need to handle a websocket connection in my Angular 2 project

```
@Injectable()
export class WsManagerService<T> extends Subject<T> {
    private socket: WebSocketSubject<any>;

    constructor() {
      super();
      ...

      this.connect();
    }

    connect(): void {
      this.socket = new WebSocketSubject(this.wsSubjectConfig);
      this.socket.subscribe(
        (m) => {
          this.handleMessage(m);
          this.next(m); /// when receiving a message, we just send it to Subject
        },
        (error: Event) => {
          if (!this.socket) {
            /// in case of an error with a loss of connection, we restore it
            this.reconnect();
          }
        });
    }

    handleMessage(message: any): void {
        if (this.isMessageConfiguration(message)) {
            // STORE GLOBAL VARIABLE
        } else if (this.isDateTime(message)) {
            ...
        }
    }

    isMessageConfiguration(object: any): object is MessageConfiguration {
        return 'rows' in object;
    }
}
```

And I need to store a message received that represent a configuration in a global variable, so that it could be retrieved by a component.

I am using this service in a component in this way

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-setup',
  templateUrl: './map-setup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-setup.component.css'],
  providers: [WsManagerService]
})
export class MapSetupComponent {
    constructor (wsManagerService: WsManagerService) {}
}
```

But I cannot resolve the '**Generic type WsManagerService requires 1 type argument**' error that I have

Where I am wrong?

Comment: check my answer it should resolve your compilation issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the `WsManagerService` service class is a generic class hence it expects a type while injecting it in the constructor of the component class. If you are not sure about the type from before then you can use `any` as the type. Your component class code should look like below -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-setup',
  templateUrl: './map-setup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-setup.component.css'],
  providers: [WsManagerService]
})
export class MapSetupComponent {
    constructor (private wsManagerService: WsManagerService<any>) {} // change it here
}
```

Here is a working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjdmlw

Comment: Thanks @Niladri, this solved the problem, but I have a new one

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[String]: 
  StaticInjectorError[String]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for String!`

Comment: @Marco24690 is it related to `providers: [WsManagerService]` ? where are u getting the error?

Comment: @Marco24690 can try updating `providers:[
    {provide:'WbSocketService', useFactory:()=>(new WsManagerService<any>())}]` and change the constructor to  `constructor (@Inject('WbSocketService') private wsManagerService: WsManagerService<any>) {}`

Comment: I get the error when I add the parameter of constructor `constructor (private wsManagerService: WsManagerService<any>)`
Tried with the solution you have proposed, but now I get this compilation error in the constructor `Expected 1-5 arguments, but got 0.
src/app/map-setup/map-setup.component.ts(32,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Inject'`

Comment: Did you import {inject } from `@angular/core`